# MP Android Chart

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hi I am using MPAndroid chart as charting library in my android app. I am trying to highlight some out of the range values on line dataset with different color (Picture 1)and if the value is beyond range then I want to also change marker-view drawable image also. [image: Picture 1]

I have achieved this (Picture 2 ) for now I have managed to change color to red  of out of the range values. How can I achieve Picture 1 in chart? [image: Picture 2]

```
private void populateChart() {
    chart = binding.lcCharts;
    chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    chart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
    chart.setPinchZoom(false);
    chart.setScaleEnabled(false);
    getXAxisData()

    LineData lineData = new LineData(setLineDataSet());
    lineData.setDrawValues(false);

    chart.setData(lineData);
    chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    chart.setDrawMarkers(false);
    chart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(true);
    chart.setMarker(new YourMarkerView(fragment.requireContext(), R.layout.layout_pop_up));
    chart.setClipChildren(false);
    chart.setClipToPadding(false);


    chart.invalidate();

    chart.notifyDataSetChanged();


}

private ArrayList<ILineDataSet> setLineDataSet() {

    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < response.size(); i++) {

        LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(setData(i),
                response.get(i).getName());
        lineDataSet.setLineWidth(3);


        lineDataSet.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(colorArray[i]));
        lineDataSet.setDrawCircleHole(false);
        lineDataSet.setCircleRadius(4);
        lineDataSet.setCircleColors(setColorOfLineDataSet(i));
        dataSet.add(lineDataSet);

    }


    return dataSet;
}

private ArrayList<Integer> setColorOfLineDataSet(int i) {
    ArrayList<Integer> color = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int j = 0; j < response.get(i).size(); j++) {

        if (!response.get(i).isNormal()) {
            color.add(R.color.Red);
        } else {
            color.add(colorArray[i]);
        }
    }

    return color;
} private void getXAxisData() {
    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    // xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
 xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(getDateArrayForXAxis()));//getDateArrayForXAxis function returns a String array of size 14 with values of dates of past two weeks.
    xAxis.setLabelCount(14, true);


}




public class MyXAxisValueFormatter extends ValueFormatter {

    private String[] mValues;

    public MyXAxisValueFormatter(String[] values) {
        this.mValues = values;
    }


    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
        String val = null;

        try {
            val = String.valueOf(mValues[(int) value]);

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        }


        return val;
    }

    /**
     * Used to draw axis labels, calls {@link #getFormattedValue(float)} by default.
     *
     * @param value float to be formatted
     * @param axis  axis being labeled
     * @return formatted string label
     */

    public String getAxisLabel(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return getFormattedValue(value);
    }


}
```

This code is crashing with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Comment: Please, post you code snippets which shows how you handle the out of range data... without code snippets we can not help you out

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi done please look into it. :)

Comment: can't we do any workaround for the same .

Comment: check the answer, I found something which can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For customizing the `Circle` shape you can use following methods of the `LineDataSet`:

- setCircleColor(/*some Color value*/)
- setCircleRadius(/* some float value */)
- setDrawCircleHole(/* boolean value */)
- setDrawFilled(/* boolean value*/)

try these out, maybe you'll find something which you want. But I don't think it will allow you to change the shape completely.

I have referred to this article for an example:https://www.studytutorial.in/android-line-chart-or-line-graph-using-mpandroid-library-tutorial

Comment: I have tried these functions already but didn't worked out for me

Comment: have you referred to the article I have mentioned?

Comment: It might point you to something which is missing in your code.

Comment: No I haven't referred the article.I will read it and let you know.
Meanwhile can you help with one more problem which I am facing  i.e X-Axis data is getting duplicate.I want to display 2 weeks dates on xAxis and it's not working around.

Comment: before I can help you out with that, I need to know how you provide `X-Axis` values.
I suggest creating a new question with more details for this.

Comment: I am editing this question. Because I can't post a new one as per the rules. please look into it .

Comment: if you are getting repeating numbers in `X-Axis` it might because of this code `mValues[(int) value]`.

Comment: Yes you are right. "value" is giving 23.1, 23.4, 23.7, 24... How can this "value" give  correct indexes like 14 labels so  0,1,2,3,.....13. Then just simply print  data of  array "mValues" ? How I can fix it?

Comment: Which customisation are you talking about?

Comment: the one you wanted with the `Circle` shape!!

Comment: I did checked the article but it didn't helped me . Are you by-chance talking about these functions :  setDrawCircleHole(/* boolean value */)

Comment: yes, I am talking about those methods to customize the `Circle` shape.